# Deploy fastapi в docker контейнере

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, fastapi

Пытаюсь запустить тестовый проект на `fastapi` на `ubuntu 20.04` c `docker`.
Пользуюсь оф доками.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn

EXPOSE 8000

COPY ./app /app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "127.0.0.1", "--port", "8000"]
```

`main.py`

```
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Optional[str] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
```

Создаю Docker image так `sudo docker build -t myimage .` . Потом запускаю в контейнере `sudo docker run -d --name mycont -p 8000:8000 myimage`.

Контейнер создается. В списке активных контейнеров вижу

```
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
333ad5104b9f myimage "uvicorn app.main:ap…" 13 seconds ago Up 12 seconds 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp mycont
```

в логах докера

```
INFO: Started server process [1]
INFO: Waiting for application startup.
INFO: Application startup complete.
INFO: Uvicorn running on 127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Но при переходе по ссылке 127.0.0.1:8000/docs страница не открывается. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка

Comment: Я не сильно понимаю в развёртывании сервера, но разве  докерфайле не надо писать команду `uvicorn maip:app`?

Comment: @MichaelTetelev ну в доках написано что не обязательно. Да даже если написать это ничего не меняется

Comment: 80 порт уже занят, да и нельзя его не root-у использовать. Когда используете 8080 смотрите логи контейнера `docker logs container-id`, там, вероятно, есть сообщение об ошибке с причиной

Comment: @RomanKonoval да, пишет cannot assign requested address docker

Comment: Попробуйте слушать только на localhost, т.е. укажите `"--host", "127.0.0.1"` в параметрах запуска. Ну и сообщение об ошибке нужно писать в текст вопроса, а не в комментарий, так как это часть вопроса.

Comment: @RomanKonoval указал в `docker logs container-id` пишет что `uvicorn` стартанул на 127.0.0.1:8080. Но при переходе по этому адресу страница не открывается

Comment: Вам нужно обновить вопрос, чтоб он отображал текущее положение вещей. Сейчас в вопросе смешано много других проблем.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129203/discussion-between--and-roman-konoval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять на:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Это происходит потому, что вы явно привязываетесь к локальному адресу внутри контейнера (в данном случае его лучше воспринимать как независимую компьютер находящийся в некой сети), тогда как у контейнера есть несколько сетей, нужная нам это `172.x.x.x`. Поэтому мы и указываем `--host 0.0.0.0` чтобы запусть сервер на всех доступных адресах на порту `8000`, чтобы при публикации порта через `-p 8000:8000` наше приложение было доступно.

Ну и пример из [документации](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/#raspberry-pi-and-other-architectures).

Comment: правильно ли я понял что в `sudo docker run -d --name mycont -p 8000:8000 myimage` я могу уазать адрес нужной сети например sudo docker run -d --name mycont -p 10.17.8.20:8000:8000 myimage?  и апишка будет доступна на любом устройстве в этой сети?

Comment: или она и так доступна в любой сети этого устройства хоть то по 127.0.0.1 или на любом другом

Comment: @Вадим чтобы выставить на любое устройство в вашей сети хост машины, ничего добавлять не нужно, обычный `-p 8000:8000`, аналогичен `-p 0.0.0.0:8000:8000`, т.е. случшает из всех сетей, но если хотите это ограничить, то можно и указать конкретный `ip`, например `-p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000`

Comment: все, я разобрался, спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

По поводу именно docs все достаточно скачать swagger-ui и поместить скопировать директорию dist в корневую директорию проекта, тогда docs откроется.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]